# Getting all data from a many to many table

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I don't get it...I have a titles table with 3 titles--`Manager`-`Secretary`-`Captain`. A user can have more than one title. So this is what I did...

```
'SELECT u.*, t.*, ut.*
 FROM users u               
      JOIN user_title ut
       ON ut.user_id = u.id
      JOIN titles t
       ON ut.title_id = t.id
  WHERE u.id = 7';
```

Now, this works just fine when I run it in `phpMyAdmin`, all 3 titles that are assigned to user.id 7 is displayed. However, when I use this in my IDE (via php), I only get back 'Manager', the first data row only. Been at this for a week now, I believe I'm losing my mind. Any suggestions?
This is my actual code...

```
 public function validateLogin($email, $pass, $title){
    global $dbh;

    $sql = 'SELECT u.*, p.*, t.*, ut.*
            FROM passwords p
                JOIN users u
                    ON p.user_id = u.id
                JOIN user_title ut
                    ON ut.user_id = u.id
                JOIN titles t
                    ON ut.title_id = t.id        
            WHERE u.email = :email AND p.password = :pass';               

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute(['email'=>$email, 'pass'=> md5($pass . $this->getSalt())]);
    $data = $stmt->fetch();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        $_SESSION['user']['title'] = $title;
        $_SESSION['user']['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user']['name'] = $data['first_name'];
        return true;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['user']['loggedin'] = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the relevant php code here.

Comment: Without looking at your php code, I would guess that you are fetching the details in to Manager(model) class from in your php code.

Comment: This is the actual code ...

Comment: I just realized I didn't use fetchAll(). That fixed it. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join instead:

```
'SELECT u.*, t.*, ut.*
 FROM users u               
      LEFT JOIN user_title ut
       ON ut.user_id = u.id
       LEFT JOIN titles t
        ON ut.title_id = t.id
  WHERE u.id = 7';
```

Comment: I tried left and right JOINs. As I already mentioned, the sql statement works when I use it in phpMyAdmin. I just can't figure out why it won't work when I try calling it in php.

Comment: Why do you close the cursor right after the if statement? Did you tried to move it "lower" in you code?